# Configuration: When does IsReadOnly take effect?

Tags: .net, configuration, readonly

This is a simple question, but one I'm not finding much information for in the docs. When dealing with custom configuration sections, collections, elements, etc., when does the `IsReadOnly` setting actually mean "read only"?

With `IsReadOnly` returning `True`, I can still do things like `MyBase.Item("property") = value;`.

Are these classes only "read only" when the configuration has been read from a .config file, but always read/write when working with the classes directly?

Answer (score 0):

`Configuration.GetSection` sets `IsReadOnly` before returning the `ConfigurationSection`. In my experience, once `IsReadOnly` is set, you can't change any properties on the configuration elements contained in the section. If you construct the config objects yourself, then `IsReadOnly` wouldn't be set unless you called `SetReadOnly()` from the derived class.